# How to get total numer of windows phone app downloads from windows phone store?

Tags: windows-phone-7, download, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I am  publishing one  windows phone app in store.Now I want to know How many users download my app.that means count of the downloads.I am searching windows dashboard on my account but not getting any count details. please help me.I want to know about the number of users download my app.Thank you in advance

Comment: Download count takes up to one week to appear on the dashboard. Just wait a few days

Comment: KoolKiz is right it can take a little while to show on your dashboard.  You could also add something like google analytics to your app to see how many people are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more user statistics when using `Google Analytics`, like crashes and exceptions, events (click on a button etc.), device models, number of users currently using your app in real-time, and of course the number of installations and active users.

I use [this SDK](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/) in my projects. Simply include the SDK via Nuget to your project by searching `googleAnalyticsSdk`, and follow the steps in the [documentation](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/documentation).

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Store dashboard has the basic things like number of downloads, demographics, etceteras. You can also download that information. Go to http://dev.windows.com, click Dashboard and login with you Microsoft account.

To have more details on the usage specific to your app you could use googleAnalytics, but when you start a Universal Windows app (Win10) you also get ApplicationInsight added to your project. This will give you a very detailed insight in your app on Azure. For more information see http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/03/20/instrumenting-your-app-for-telemetry-and-analytics/

Martin